# "This BIN image seems to be invalid optical disk image" - AnyTolSO 3.9.6 Lite

Tags: assembly, iso, bin

Converting my simple .bin Boot Sector file [converted from .asm] to an iso so I can run it in VirtualBox, and I experience this error when I try to convert it to an iso.

`18:39:54 - Checking source image... 18:39:54 - There's no .cue sheet to match the image. We assume that the image contains only 1 data track 18:39:54 - This BIN image seems to be invalid optical disk image, please contact support for assistance.`

This is the code in the ASM file.

`jmp $

times 510-($-$$) db 0
db 0x55, 0xaa`

I couldn't really do anything, there's not much buttons here.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwnrI.png)

Comment: Try padding your image to a larger size, and preferably to a multiple of 2048 bytes.